# forking in linux about COW

Tags: linux, process, fork, copy-on-write

In linux, I know it's implemented by COW because of wasting. But, in the book says, when child calls exec() right after fork(), address spaces are never copied.
But I think if child use exec(), it means making new data or codes in the address space which is not yet copied. So when exec() is called, then address spaced is copied(Copy on Write), and new data or codes are written in here.

Am I wrong? Why exec() calls never copy parent's things?

Or If child calls exec(), then child just make his own mm_struct and write new data in his own address space which is newly made?(not copied from parent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exec is library wrapper around the execve kernel call. there's going to be some stack activity before the execve starts (even if execve is called directly), so there will be at-least one stack block copied on write before the exec kicks in disconnects from the process context.

meanwhile the parent process will have been doing lots of copy on write before the child disconnects.